# multiple update in laravel from input form with name as id and name as names

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, database, eloquent

Am try to update the data in my table from input form using eloquent:
This the output of my code

[image]

So what i want is that when i click submit i want all the data to be update respective of its ID

My table looks like this

[image]

Here is my code in Blade

```
<form action="{{url('update/users')}}" method="post">
 @csrf
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Names</th>
     </tr>
     @foreach($data as $users)
     <tr>
     <td><input type="" name="id" value="{{$users->id}}" ></td>
     <td><input type="" name="name" value="{{$users->name}}" ></td>
     </tr> 
     @endforeach  
  </tbody>  
</table>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

in Controller

```
  public function update(Request $request){
     
     //code here
     // $users = Users::

     return back()->with('success','Successfully');
   }
```

Comment: you will only get one 'id' and one 'name' on the server side because of how the inputs in the loop are named

Comment: Where's the code that updates any data? What's your question about this topic?

Comment: @NicoHaase ```$users = Users::where("id" ,$request->id)->update(["name" => $request->name]);```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to update multiple resources in db you can accomplish this using:

first you must edit your form to send multiple data to server :
you must set type of inputs. the type of id input must be hidden becasue user can not edit it . this input will be used in controller to determine the user to update .

you can send a array parameter to server. to accomplish this you can
set the name attribute of input as array

```
<form action="{{url('update/users')}}" method="post">
 @csrf
<table>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
         <th>ID</th>
         <th>Names</th>
     </tr>
     @foreach($data as $key=> $users)
     <tr>
     <td><input type="hidden" name="users[{{$key}}][id]" value="{{$users->id}}" ></td>
     <td><input type="text" name="users[{{$key}}][name]" value="{{$users->name}}" ></td>
     </tr> 
     @endforeach  
  </tbody>  
</table>
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

so the `users` in request is a array that each element is array with id and name key

```
public function update(Request $request){
    
       foreach($request->input('users') as $user){
         $id=$user['id'] ;
         $name=$user['name'] ;
         User::find($id)->update([
            'name'=>$name 
           ]) ;
      }
   

     return back()->with('success','Successfully');
   }
```

Comment: This the error am getting ```Undefined array key "name"```

Comment: I updated the answer. a key is need too

Comment: Thanx, Question How do i use this query in this case ```User::where("id" ,$id)->update(["name" => $name]);```

Comment: your query is correct. it will update each user with specified `$id`.